# Json to CSV in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, azure, export-to-csv

I'm working with Powershell, querying Azure Log analytics with the [LogAnalyticsQuery](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Tools/PowerShell-Cmdlets) module using `Invoke-LogAnalyticsQuery`.

I have the results

```
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
                {"name": "Computer","type": "string"},
                {"name": "TimeGenerated","type": "datetime"},
                {"name": "AggregatedValue","type": "real"
                }
            ],
            "rows": [
                ["VPN-Server","2018-02-20T07:30:00Z",5.083333333333333],
                ["SARMAD-SurfacePro4","2018-02-20T07:30:00Z",14.598250052664012],
                ["VPN-Server","2018-02-20T07:00:00Z",4.9523809523809526],
                ["SARMAD-SurfacePro4","2018-02-20T07:00:00Z",12.104500129109331],
                ["SARMAD-SurfacePro4","2018-02-20T08:00:00Z",20.936097813082174],
                ["VPN-Server","2018-02-20T08:00:00Z",4.245614035087719]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From the sample above, how I can use powershell to convert it to something like this?:

```
Reportname, Computer, TimeGenerated, AggregatedValue

Manual Value, JsonValue, JsonValue, JsonValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it similar to this:

```
function Get-Tables
{
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$Json)

    process
    {
        foreach ($table in ($Json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables)
        {
            foreach ($row in $table.rows)
            {
                $result = New-Object PSObject
                $columnIndex = 0

                foreach ($column in $table.columns)
                {
                    Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $column.Name -Value ($row[$columnIndex++])
                }

                $result
            }
        }
    }
}

$json | Get-Tables | Export-Csv
```

Where `$json` is string variable with value from the question example.

```
$json = '{  "tables": [   ...  ] }'
```

Comment: getteing error ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At line:7 char:37
+         foreach ($table in ($Json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables)
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: what about if it was Json and not a string? the data is the results of the Invoke-LogAnalyticsQuery, then I guess I need to remove the ConvertFrom-Json

Comment: I need to use $results.Response.Content when I run $results = Invoke-LogAnalyticsQuery and the result is a string ... now it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `convertfrom-json` and can finally use `export-csv` to export:

```
$a='{"tables":[{"name":"PrimaryResult","columns":[{"name":"Computer","type":"string"},{"name":"TimeGenerated","type":"datetime"},{"name":"AggregatedValue","type":"real"}],"rows":[["VPN-Server","2018-02-20T07:30:00Z",5.083333333333333],["SARMAD-SurfacePro4","2018-02-20T07:30:00Z",14.598250052664012],["VPN-Server","2018-02-20T07:00:00Z",4.9523809523809526],["SARMAD-SurfacePro4","2018-02-20T07:00:00Z",12.104500129109331],["SARMAD-SurfacePro4","2018-02-20T08:00:00Z",20.936097813082174],["VPN-Server","2018-02-20T08:00:00Z",4.245614035087719]]}]}'
($a | ConvertFrom-Json).tables.columns.name
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Data-base: Acceptance would be appreciable.

Comment: one more question what about the rows? I get then in one line like 1,2,3,1,2,3, is there away to split them them?

Comment: Yes even you can use `-Split ","` to split it or you can directly use the string method `$object.split(',')`